# Destructure given Array type into new types

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have a type

```js
type Args = [foo: string, bar: number, baz: number];
```

and we wanted to construct a new type

```js
type NewArgs = [bar: number, baz: number];
```

from that `Args` type. Is that possible? I'm probably missing something. What I'm thinking of is something like "type destructuring"

```js
type [Foo, ...NewArgs] = Args;
```

where

```js
// Foo === string
// NewArgs === [bar: number, baz: number]
```

Edit:

I know that the following is possible but there must me a more clever way of doing it, right?

```js
type NewArgs = [Args[1], Args[2]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is a bit unintuitive but this is how it's done:

```
type NewArgs = Args extends [any, ...infer U] ? U : never
```

See also [Variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types)

Comment: Oh well. That _is_ unintuitive. Thanks for the pointer!